# URL to Active Admin edit pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm developing a rails application that administers some data with Active Admin.  One of my views exports a PDF that summarizes data in the back-end.  I'd like to link each entry in the PDF to the "edit" view in Active Admin associated with that resource.

My question is how to get the URL to a specific Active Admin edit page for a model instance.  I can't seem to find the URLs using `rake routes` or using other methods I found in the documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For all the projects I've used activeadmin on, the edit routes have always been `edit_admin_model`, with a path that looks like `/admin/model/:id/edit`. Given this, I would expect your app to have an `edit_admin_model_url(model_id)` for each model you have an ActiveAdmin file for, that you could use in a link helper when compiling your PDF.

If that doesn't help, could you post the output to `rake routes` for us?

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this answer.  It turns out my problem was unrelated though, I was trying to get a route inside a model class, rather than a controller or view.